# Select last wrong item from the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with items, that have a `Time` property. If I want to select all items where `Time` is equal or bigger then some `startTime`, then I write something like this:

```
var newList = list.Where(i => (i.Time >= startTime));
```

But now I also want to get the last item, where the time is smaller than `startTime`. Is there a better way to implement this?

For example I have list where items have `Time` from this list:

```
[5:32, 5:46, 5:51, 6:07, 6:11, 6:36]
```

We specify a `startTime` as `6:00`.

Now we want to get this times:

```
[5:51, 6:07, 6:11, 6:36]
```

Comment: Clarify: "get a last item, which time is smaller then 'startTime'"

Comment: `Time` property is of `DateTime` type?

Comment: Yes, Time property is of DateTime type.

Comment: Install Skeet's [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) extension methods. Then you can use `MaxBy`.

Comment: @Pedro No, this time interval could be from minutes to a lot of hours.

Comment: @Pedro Because I want to know what happens between 6:00 and 6:07. And this is described by the last inserted item.

Comment: Is `newList` in order?

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Yes, list is sorted by `Time` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the whole List at once:

```
var newList = list
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Time)
    .Take(list.Count(j => j.Time >= startTime) + 1)
    .OrderBy(k => k.Time); //Optional
```

With Cognition's suggestion:

```
var newList = list
    .OrderBy(i => i.Time)
    .Skip(list.Count(j => j.Time < startTime - 1));
```

Comment: you can replace the OrderByDescending and Take with a Skip,                `var newList = list.Skip(list.Count(j => j.Time < startTime) - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var smallerThan = list
    .Where(i => i.Time < startTime)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Time)
    .Take(1)
    .Concat(list.Where(i => i.Time => startTime));
```

Comment: Just pass the `Where` predicate directly to `Last`. Much shorter.

Comment: And? I didn't say to remove the `OrderBy`. I just said nix the `Where`  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result=list
  .Where(i=>i.Time<startTime)
  .OrderBy(i=>i.Time)
  .Last()
  .Concat(list
    .OrderBy(i=>i.Time)
    .Where(i=>i.Time>=startTime)
  );
```

or

```
var result=list
  .OrderBy(i=>i.Time)
  .Last(i=>i.Time<startTime)
  .Concat(list
    .OrderBy(i=>i.Time)
    .Where(i=>i.Time>=startTime)
  );
```

Comment: Literally dozens of ways of writing this, but this is likely the one I would use myself.  Another approach would be to find the time of the first record less than start time, and select all that are greater or equal to that.

Answer (score 1):

As your list is in order of the property you want to find, you can do something along the lines of

```
List<int> things = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int threshold = 4;
var newThings = things.Skip(things.FindIndex(x => x >= threshold) - 1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newThings));
```

Which outputs

> 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Extending it to use a class with a `Time` property which happens to be a `TimeSpan`:

```
class Z
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
};

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Z> zs = new List<Z>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            zs.Add(new Z { Time = new TimeSpan(i, rand.Next(0,61), rand.Next(0,61)) });
        }

        TimeSpan threshold = new TimeSpan(4,0,0);
        var newThings = zs.Skip(zs.FindIndex(x => x.Time >= threshold) - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newThings.Select(x => x.Time.ToString("c"))));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Sample output:

> 03:03:57, 04:09:37, 05:14:44, 06:58:55, 07:40:33, 08:37:06, 09:10:06

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers seem to require a descending orderby. But you can easily avoid this with a clean one liner and good efficiency:

```
var newList = list.Skip(list.Count(j => j.Time < startTime) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = list
    .Where(i => (i.Time >= startTime))
    .ToList()
    .Add(list
        .Where(i => (i.Time < startTime))
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Time)
        .FirstOrDefault()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int lastItemIndex = list.OrderBy(D => D.TimeOfDay).ToList()
                        .FindLastIndex(D => D.TimeOfDay < startTime);

var newList = list.Where(D => list.IndexOf(D) > lastItemIndex);
```